# Pandas : Fillna for all columns, except two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder how can we fill the NaNs from all columns of a dataframe, except some.
For example, I have a dataframe with 20 columns, I want to fill the NaN for all except two columns (in my case, NaN are replaced by the mean).

```
df = df.drop(['col1','col2], 1).fillna(df.mean())
```

I tried this, but I don't think it's the best way to achieve this (also, i want to avoid the inplace=true arg).

Thank's

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916989/replace-missing-values-in-all-columns-except-one-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select which columns to use `fillna` on. Assuming you have 20 columns and you want to fill all of them except 'col1' and 'col2' you can create a list with the ones you want to fill:

```
f = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ['col1','col2']]
df[f] = df[f].fillna(df[f].mean())

print(df)

   col1  col2      col3  col4  ...     col17  col18     col19  col20
0   1.0   1.0  1.000000   1.0  ...  1.000000      1  1.000000      1
1   NaN   NaN  2.666667   2.0  ...  2.000000      2  2.000000      2
2   NaN   3.0  3.000000   1.5  ...  2.333333      3  2.333333      3
3   4.0   4.0  4.000000   1.5  ...  4.000000      4  4.000000      4

              (2.66666) was the mean
```

---

```
# Initial DF:

{'col1': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col2': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col3': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col4': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: nan},
 'col5': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col6': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'col7': {0: nan, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col8': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col9': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'col10': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col11': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col12': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'col13': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col14': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0},
 'col15': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'col16': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 3.0, 3: nan},
 'col17': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col18': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'col19': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: nan, 3: 4.0},
 'col20': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}}
```

Comment: Much better, ans safer way than drop cols in another df for concatenate them after all, ... Thank's a lot for your answer :)